# Laravel: Error in installing laravel breeze

Tags: php, laravel, breeze, laravel-9, laravel-breeze

i tried to install laravel breeze but it gave me this error:

```
  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
- laravel/breeze[v1.19.0, ..., v1.19.2] conflict with laravel/framework <9.37.0.
- laravel/breeze[v1.20.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require php ^8.1.0 -> your php version (8.0.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework is locked to version v9.22.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/breeze ^1.19 -> satisfiable by laravel/breeze[v1.19.0, ..., 1.x-dev].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/breeze:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/breeze:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I wants to install laravel breeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in your errors, the version of laravel/breeze that you are going to install doesn't match with your php version and conflict with your laravel framework. Try doing as the error suggest:

composer require laravel/breeze:*

If it doesn't work, try upgrading your php version, such as php ^8.1.0

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you have `PHP 8.0.2` running but the `breeze 1.20.0` you are trying to install requires `PHP 8.1.0`.

The best way to handle this will be to download and install the required [PHP version](https://www.php.net/downloads) or this [breeze version](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/breeze#v1.19.2)

You can specify a breeze version in the following way:

```
composer require laravel/breeze:^1.19.0
```